# Node.js .match() method correct usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, steam

I bought some code from a guy, and then I decided I want to modify it. First of all, it is written in Node.js and I have very little (none) programming experience with node.js, although I know decent python and a bit of C# so I kind of understood it. Although, as soon as I wanted to start editing the code, I wasn't successful in replicating what he did.

```
steamFriends.on('friendMsg', (id, msg) => {
  if (config.get('admins').indexOf(id) == -1) return;
  if (msg.indexOf('!price') == 0) {
    var match = msg.match(/!price (director|audition) ([\.0-9]+)/);
    if (!match) steamFriends.sendMessage(id, 'Usage: !price <director or audtion> <price> (e.g. !price director 3.77)');
    else {
      steamFriends.sendMessage(id, 'Successfully set price of '+match[1] + ' reels to '+match[2] + '!');
      PRICES[match[1] == 'audition' ? 0 : 1] = parseFloat(match[2]);
      changePrices();
    }
  }
  else if (msg.indexOf('!changename') == 0) {
    var name = msg.match(/!changename ([\A-Z]+)/);
    steamFriends.setPersonaName(name)
  }
});
```

The top one is obviously his, and the bottom one is mine. What exactly am I doing wrong? I think the .match() method is wrong to use here, but I don't know what to use instead of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bottom one" - the last `else if`? If so describe what you are trying to make it do

Comment: @DominicTobias The bottom one is the last else if. I am trying to take a string (ex. !changename Hello World) and take only the 'Hello World' Part and pass it into steamFriends.setPersonaName(name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to get the username which comes in the following string: `!changename username`

Here's the part of "your" code fixed:

```
else if (msg.indexOf('!changename') == 0) {
    var name = msg.match(/!changename ([A-Z]+)/i); //Added i flag (Case insensitive
    if(name)
       steamFriends.setPersonaName(name[1]); //The username will be in name[1]
}
```

You don't need to escape `\A` in the character set, `[A-Z]` is enough, and I added the `i` flag, which I believe you need, remove it if you only need upper case letters.

[.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can be used there perfectly, the problem is that you need to know that `.match` returns an array of matches.

```js
var string = "!changename Foo";

var matches = string.match(/!changename ([A-Z]+)/i);

document.body.innerHTML = "0: " + matches[0] + "<br>1: " + matches[1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Although, if I try to do !changename Hello World , the changename function works fine but it only changes the name to 'Hello' Why is this?

Comment: I realized it is because of the A-Z and I cannot add spaces in the name. Or any other character that isn't in the alphabet. How can I change this? Why did you add the + ?

Comment: Change it to [A-Z ]+ (a space added in the set,  if numbers are allowed, Change A-Z to \w)

Comment: Thank you so much ! You're the best